# Earliest point to set some sort of splash screen?

Tags: linux, boot, bootsplash

I am currently working on a linux based game console (raspbian). I am struggling with placing the slpash-screen correctly. I'd like the splash-screen to be shown as early as possible in the boot sequence. Preferably as soon as the power-button is pressed.

How do I create the slpash screen as early as possible. I tried plymouth, which is early, but I'd like it even earlier.

Comment: What boot loader are you using?

Comment: Sadly, I am not able to name the bootloader. It is the default raspberry pi bootloader. See here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10489/how-does-raspberry-pi-boot